# How to export Illustrator layers as individual images?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, illustrator-scripting

I have an Illustrator file that contains patterns. I'd like to export each pattern as an individual image to use in this new program that I'm trying called Sketch. Is there a batch processing script that exports layers as PNG or SVG? I'd like to have each geometric pattern available as a PNG, not as one large file.

Any thoughts?

[image: png]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the patterns are indeed on individual layers, you may be able to use scripting to export each layer as an individual png.

**Carlos Canto** wrote a [**script for Illustrator**](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5351462#5351462) and posted it in the Adobe forums.

In case of link rot, here's Carlos' script:

```
#target Illustrator

//  script.name = exportLayersAsCSS_PNGs.jsx;
//  script.description = mimics the Save for Web, export images as CSS Layers (images only);
//  script.requirements = an open document; tested with CS5 on Windows. 
//  script.parent = carlos canto // 05/24/13; All rights reseved
//  script.elegant = false;


/**
* export layers as PNG
* @author Niels Bosma
*/
// Adapted to export images as CSS Layers by CarlosCanto


if (app.documents.length>0) {
    main();
}
else alert('Cancelled by user');


function main() {
    var document = app.activeDocument;
    var afile = document.fullName;
    var filename = afile.name.split('.')[0];


    var folder = afile.parent.selectDlg("Export as CSS Layers (images only)...");


    if(folder != null)
    { 
        var activeABidx = document.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex();
        var activeAB = document.artboards[activeABidx]; // get active AB        
        var abBounds = activeAB.artboardRect;// left, top, right, bottom


        showAllLayers();
        var docBounds = document.visibleBounds;
        activeAB.artboardRect = docBounds;


        var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
        options.antiAliasing = true;
        options.transparency = true;
        options.artBoardClipping = true;

        var n = document.layers.length;
        hideAllLayers ();
        for(var i=n-1, k=0; i>=0; i--, k++)
        {
            //hideAllLayers();
            var layer = document.layers[i];
            layer.visible = true;


            var file = new File(folder.fsName + '/' +filename+ '-' + k +".png");

            document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
            layer.visible = false;
        }

        showAllLayers();
        activeAB.artboardRect = abBounds;
    }


    function hideAllLayers()
    {
        forEach(document.layers, function(layer) {
            layer.visible = false;
        });
    }


    function showAllLayers()
    {
        forEach(document.layers, function(layer) {
            layer.visible = true;
        }); 
    }


    function forEach(collection, fn)
    {
        var n = collection.length;
        for(var i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            fn(collection[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Copy and paste this into a text file and save the text file with a .jsx suffix. Then place the .jsx file into Adobe Illustrator CS(x)/Presets/[your language]/Scripts. After relaunching Illustrator, the script should be visible via `File > Scripts` within Illustrator.

Comment: FYI, the script posted above doesn't work in Illustrator CC, it gives me: Error 8, Syntax error. Line 1:

Comment: The script works absolutely fine in Illustrator CC here.

Comment: I was also getting syntax error on line 1. When I reopened the .jsx there was additional code above the original line 1 from code above. I deleted everything above #target Illustrator saved the .jsx file. I relaunched Illustrator and the script works fine now. I am also using CC

Comment: Here's updated version that uses the layer name in the file name instead of a numeric counter (so "mydoc-layername.png" instead of "mydoc-1.png") ... if anyone else needs like I did.  https://gist.github.com/34e54d199de123b8e3c50a305f23115e

Answer (score 5):

For simplicity and speed of workflow, I would probably use the slice tool to create slices for the individual patterns, then Save for Web, making sure that "All Slices" was selected in the "Export:" dropdown. If I were building from scratch, I'd put each pattern on its own artboard (which you could still do) and use File>Export with the "Use Artboards" option checked.